# How do I use fallback fonts in JavaFX?

Tags: css, javafx, font-face

For a project I am currently working on in JavaFX, I want the user to be able to enter a name of a Deck which can contain multiple languages (e.g. 日本語 N4 Vocab).

To be able to display fonts from multiple languages correctly, I tried specifying multiple fonts in the css of a textfield like this in a stack:

```
.text-field {
    -fx-font-family: "Work Sans", "Noto Sans JP";
}
```

But I realised that JavaFX *does not support comma-separated series of font family names in the -fx-font-family property.*

So I have a few questions:

1. Is using fallback fonts as above the correct way to support using multiple fonts for a Label / TextField?
2. If it is, how do I go around this limitation to implement this feature.
3. If not, what else should I do to improve the rendering of multi-language Strings in JavaFX?

Update | This is what I tried:

```
@font-face {
    src: url('WorkSans-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    src: url('WorkSans-Bold.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    src: url('NotoSans-Regular.ttf');
}

.text-area {
    -fx-font-size: 30;
    -fx-font-family: 'Work Sans';
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

And this is the what the TextArea displays when unsupported characters are entered:

[image: TextArea with unsupported characters]

Answer (score 0):

From the [JavaFX CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introlimitations):

> JavaFX CSS does not support comma-separated series of font family names in the -fx-font-family property. The optional line height parameter when specifying fonts is not supported. There is no equivalent for the font-variant property.

Possible workarounds:

1. In your CSS: you can define and use multiple fonts with @font-face.

```
@font-face {
  src: url("../fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
}
    
.my-text {
  -fx-font-family: roboto;
}
```

2. In your code: you can check/use Font.loadFont() or Font.font().

Update: font-face code added

My demo code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TextArea ta = new TextArea();

        VBox vbox = new VBox(ta);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 640, 480);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX App");
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

style.css

```
@font-face {
    src: url("fonts/WorkSans-Regular.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    src: url("fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf");
}

.text-area {
    -fx-font-size: 30;
    -fx-font-family: 'Work Sans';
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

My screenshot on macOS Mojave:

[image]

Maybe you don't have the fonts of different languages in your OS. Try to install the fonts in your OS.

Update 2: Demo code added.

Comment: I can set multiple @font-faces and load multiple fonts but I am still not sure how to get a Node to use more than one font

Comment: @r0wletc0der Answer updated. You can define and use multiple fonts with font-face in your CSS. Just use font-face definitions top on the CSS.

Comment: One issue I'm facing is that if Roboto does not support Japanese characters, JavaFX will default to using another font, which I can't control, and the font weights will be different. Is there anyway to use both Roboto and Noto Sans JP together?

Comment: @r0wletc0der check please my demo code with JavaFX 11 or never.

Comment: I'm using Windows, and I need to send the .jar to other people, so preferably the fonts are already embedded. And simplified chinese dont look right because it uses japanese glyphs first, so characters in chinese but not in Japanese appear in a different font

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the top rated answer, it is not possible to directly configure a fallback font via JavaFX's css.

But it is possible when leveraging the internal JavaFX API. It is possible by directly manipulating the underlying `FontResource` of the `Font` via the Reflection API.

Here is a [demo](https://github.com/duoduobingbing/javafx-custom-font-fallback-demo) that shows how this can be done with JavaFX 21.