# Support multiple language fonts in a single TextField in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, fonts

I am new to JavaFX, and I was wondering how I can support multiple language fonts (i.e. Chinese, English, Hindi, etc.).

Currently, when I set my TextField to use a font family which support Latin characters in a css, characters from other languages will not render correctly.

[image]

This is my css:

```css
@font-face {
    src: url('WorkSans-Regular.ttf');
}
.text-area {
    -fx-font-size: 25;
    -fx-font-family: 'Work Sans';
}
```

I realised that JavaFX css does not allow for comma sepearated fonts for font stacks and fallback fonts like below:

```css
@font-face {
    src: url('WorkSans-Regular.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    src: url('NotoSansSC-Regular.ttf');
}
.text-area {
    -fx-font-size: 25;
    -fx-font-family: 'Work Sans', 'Noto Sans SC';
}
```

Is there another way to support typing in multiple languages?
My project requires the user to enter text in multiple languages, and I need to ensure that the fonts are embedded into the .jar so that each user will have the same UI.

Comment: With my very little knowledge on this subject, my guess is that you should find a font that covers most of the languages you want to support. I would look at different Unicode fonts if I were you. According to the web, `Arial Unicode` is a good start. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font

Comment: hmm .. how is this different from your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62934939/how-do-i-use-fallback-fonts-in-javafx (can't judge, not much knowledge with different fonts ;)? Seems the answer was not-really-supported? Anyway, if it is different enough, don't start from zero but add a reference to that old question and explain exactly what's new :)

Comment: Can you determine what language is being used at runtime? Is the language a user configuration? Is the same language used throughout the application or are multiple languages used simultaneously?

Comment: @Slaw I am planning for the user to be able to name items. So I am expecting the user to be able to enter in any language. If using multiple fonts concurrently is not an option should I restrict the user to type in latin characters?

Comment: Well, I was going to suggest using a custom `javafx.css.PseudoClass` (or multiple) that you could then use in your CSS file to choose the appropriate font. Not having a clear way to determine the language used makes that more complicated. Though I suppose you could attempt to inspect the individual `char`s to try and guess the language (if that's possible).

Comment: @Slaw yes I intent to do something similar with PseudoClasses for another part of the app where the user can choose the font they want to use, though I guess I will try to find a library which can help me determine which language each char belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Work Sans';                  /*  add this line  */
        src: url('WorkSans-Regular.ttf');
    }
    
    .text-area {
        -fx-font-size: 25;
        -fx-font-family: 'Work Sans';
    }
```

Comment: I am able to set the font Work Sans, but Work Sans does not support simplified chinese characters. Is there a way to use Work Sans for latin characters and use Noto Sans SC for Chinese characters?

Comment: your problem withe the font.tff
this font " https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans+JP?preview.text=%E4%BD%86+fff+&preview.text_type=custom " is suport latin and chinois